# is there an graphql api to get discount code by id in shopify-admin-api?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

ive tried graphql's `discountCode` api but it only accepts price rule ids.the discount code was created by `priceRuleDiscountCodeCreate` API.

Comment: Check this GraphQL query, may be helps you [Link](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-04/queries/codeDiscountNodeByCode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
{
  codeDiscountNode(id:"gid://shopify/DiscountCodeNode/1111111"){
    id
    
  }
}
```

Where 111111 is your discount id.

But depends on what information you want to extract